# Taliwindcss alert dismiss button not working only when inserted from input onchange event listener

Tags: javascript, html, tailwind-css

I created a function which shows an alert box through a wipe in animation and after sometime, wipes it out. The function just inserts an element containing the alert box in the DOM on calling it (the alert box is copied from flowbite website [here](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/alerts/)

```js
function showSuccessAlert(content, timeoutTime = 50000) {
  const alert = document.querySelector("#alert");
  let alertChild = document.createElement("div");
  var classList =
    `flex items-center p-4 mb-4 text-green-800 border-t-4 border-green-300 bg-green-50 dark:text-green-400 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-green-800`.split(
      " "
    );

  for (let className of classList) {
    alertChild.classList.add(className);
  }

  alertChild.id = `alert-box-${alert.childElementCount}`;
  alertChild.setAttribute("role", "alert");
  alertChild.innerHTML = `
 
  <svg
    class="flex-shrink-0 w-4 h-4"
    aria-hidden="true"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    fill="currentColor"
    viewBox="0 0 20 20"
  >
    <path
      d="M10 .5a9.5 9.5 0 1 0 9.5 9.5A9.51 9.51 0 0 0 10 .5ZM9.5 4a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0 3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0-3ZM12 15H8a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h1v-3H8a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v4h1a1 1 0 0 1 0 2Z"
    />
  </svg>
  <div id="alertContent" class="ml-3 text-sm font-medium">
    ${content}
  </div>
  <button
    type="button"
    class="ml-auto -mx-1.5 -my-1.5 bg-green-50 text-green-500 rounded-lg focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-400 p-1.5 hover:bg-green-200 inline-flex items-center justify-center h-8 w-8 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-green-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700"
    data-dismiss-target="#${alertChild.id}"
    aria-label="Close"
  >
    <span class="sr-only">Dismiss</span>
    <svg
      class="w-3 h-3"
      aria-hidden="true"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      fill="none"
      viewBox="0 0 14 14"
    >
      <path
        stroke="currentColor"
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
        stroke-width="2"
        d="m1 1 6 6m0 0 6 6M7 7l6-6M7 7l-6 6"
      />
    </svg>
  </button>
`;
  alertChild.style.transition = "transform 0.75s";

  alert.appendChild(alertChild);

  alertChild.style.animation = "wipe-alert 0.75s ease-in-out";

  setTimeout(() => {
    alertChild.style.transform = "translateX(100%)";
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert.removeChild(alertChild);
    }, 0.75 * 1000);
  }, timeoutTime);
}
```

The Function works fine. The dismiss button also works in most of the cases. But when the function is called inside `onchange` function of an input(type file), the dismiss button stops working. The alert box is still shown and everything else is working, just the dismiss button is doing nothing in that case.

#### Below snippet shows the problem

```js
function showSuccessAlert(content, timeoutTime = 3000) {
  const alert = document.querySelector("#alert");
  let alertChild = document.createElement("div");
  var classList =
    `flex items-center p-4 mb-4 text-green-800 border-t-4 border-green-300 bg-green-50 dark:text-green-400 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-green-800`.split(
      " "
    );

  for (let className of classList) {
    alertChild.classList.add(className);
  }

  alertChild.id = `alert-box-${alert.childElementCount}`;
  alertChild.setAttribute("role", "alert");
  alertChild.innerHTML = `
 
  <svg
    class="flex-shrink-0 w-4 h-4"
    aria-hidden="true"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    fill="currentColor"
    viewBox="0 0 20 20"
  >
    <path
      d="M10 .5a9.5 9.5 0 1 0 9.5 9.5A9.51 9.51 0 0 0 10 .5ZM9.5 4a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0 3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0-3ZM12 15H8a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h1v-3H8a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v4h1a1 1 0 0 1 0 2Z"
    />
  </svg>
  <div id="alertContent" class="ml-3 text-sm font-medium">
    ${content}
  </div>
  <button
    type="button"
    class="ml-auto -mx-1.5 -my-1.5 bg-green-50 text-green-500 rounded-lg focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-400 p-1.5 hover:bg-green-200 inline-flex items-center justify-center h-8 w-8 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-green-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700"
    data-dismiss-target="#${alertChild.id}"
    aria-label="Close"
  >
    <span class="sr-only">Dismiss</span>
    <svg
      class="w-3 h-3"
      aria-hidden="true"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      fill="none"
      viewBox="0 0 14 14"
    >
      <path
        stroke="currentColor"
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
        stroke-width="2"
        d="m1 1 6 6m0 0 6 6M7 7l6-6M7 7l-6 6"
      />
    </svg>
  </button>
`;
  alertChild.style.transition = "transform 0.75s";

  alert.appendChild(alertChild);

  alertChild.style.animation = "wipe-alert 0.75s ease-in-out";

  setTimeout(() => {
    alertChild.style.transform = "translateX(100%)";
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert.removeChild(alertChild);
    }, 0.75 * 1000);
  }, timeoutTime);
}

const uploadInput = document.querySelector("#upload input");
uploadInput.onchange = () => {
  showSuccessAlert("Uploading Image")
}
showSuccessAlert("Working When Called Outside onchange")
```

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
#alert {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  right: 10px;
  max-width: 300px;
  z-index:100;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.7.0/flowbite.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  
<div id="alert"></div>

<div id="upload" class="ms-auto w-screen flex content-center justify-center flex-wrap items-center my-10">
  <div class="text-4xl my-5 text-purple-700 font-bold">
    <svg class="w-6 h-6 text-purple-700 inline" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 18">
          <path
            d="M18 0H2a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v14a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h16a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2Zm-5.5 4a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0 3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0-3Zm4.376 10.481A1 1 0 0 1 16 15H4a1 1 0 0 1-.895-1.447l3.5-7A1 1 0 0 1 7.468 6a.965.965 0 0 1 .9.5l2.775 4.757 1.546-1.887a1 1 0 0 1 1.618.1l2.541 4a1 1 0 0 1 .028 1.011Z"
          />
        </svg> Upload Photos
  </div>
  <div class="relative flex items-center justify-center w-11/12">
    <label for="dropzone-file" class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full h-64 border-2 border-gray-300 border-dashed rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-bray-800 dark:bg-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:border-gray-500 dark:hover:bg-gray-600">
          <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center pt-5 pb-6">
            <svg
              class="w-16 h-16 mb-4 text-purple-700 dark:text-purple-900"
              aria-hidden="true"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              fill="none"
              viewBox="0 0 20 16"
            >
              <path
                stroke="currentColor"
                stroke-linecap="round"
                stroke-linejoin="round"
                stroke-width="2"
                d="M13 13h3a3 3 0 0 0 0-6h-.025A5.56 5.56 0 0 0 16 6.5 5.5 5.5 0 0 0 5.207 5.021C5.137 5.017 5.071 5 5 5a4 4 0 0 0 0 8h2.167M10 15V6m0 0L8 8m2-2 2 2"
              />
            </svg>
            <p class="mb-2 text-lg text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
              <span class="font-semibold text-purple-700 dark:text-purple-950"
                >Click to upload</span
              >
              or drag and drop
            </p>
            <p class="text-xs text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
              PNG, JPG, or JPEG
            </p>
          </div>
          <input
            id="dropzone-file"
            type="file"
            class="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full opacity-0 cursor-pointer"
            multiple
            accept="image/jpg, image/png, image/jpeg"
          />
        </label>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.7.0/flowbite.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The dismiss button works for me. Can you show, in more details, how to reproduce this issue?

Comment: the initial dismiss button is just to show the working case without uploading. Try uploading an image. The Dismiss button will not work after there is a change in input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flowbite's JavaScript only seems to register dismiss elements once on the [`window` `load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event). The `showSuccessAlert("Working When Called Outside onchange")` call happens before the `load` event, hence it works.

On the other hand the `showSuccessAlert()` call in the `change` event listener would realistically happen after the `load` event and hence does not work. To work around this, consider using their [JavaScript API](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/alerts/#javascript-behaviour) by using the `Dismiss` class to instantiate the dismiss button:

```js
function showSuccessAlert(content, timeoutTime = 3000) {
  const alert = document.querySelector("#alert");
  let alertChild = document.createElement("div");
  var classList =
    `flex items-center p-4 mb-4 text-green-800 border-t-4 border-green-300 bg-green-50 dark:text-green-400 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-green-800`.split(
      " "
    );

  for (let className of classList) {
    alertChild.classList.add(className);
  }

  alertChild.id = `alert-box-${alert.childElementCount}`;
  alertChild.setAttribute("role", "alert");
  alertChild.innerHTML = `
 
  <svg
    class="flex-shrink-0 w-4 h-4"
    aria-hidden="true"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    fill="currentColor"
    viewBox="0 0 20 20"
  >
    <path
      d="M10 .5a9.5 9.5 0 1 0 9.5 9.5A9.51 9.51 0 0 0 10 .5ZM9.5 4a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0 3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0-3ZM12 15H8a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h1v-3H8a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v4h1a1 1 0 0 1 0 2Z"
    />
  </svg>
  <div id="alertContent" class="ml-3 text-sm font-medium">
    ${content}
  </div>
  <button
    type="button"
    class="ml-auto -mx-1.5 -my-1.5 bg-green-50 text-green-500 rounded-lg focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-400 p-1.5 hover:bg-green-200 inline-flex items-center justify-center h-8 w-8 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-green-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700"
    aria-controls="${alertChild.id}"
    aria-label="Close"
  >
    <span class="sr-only">Dismiss</span>
    <svg
      class="w-3 h-3"
      aria-hidden="true"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      fill="none"
      viewBox="0 0 14 14"
    >
      <path
        stroke="currentColor"
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
        stroke-width="2"
        d="m1 1 6 6m0 0 6 6M7 7l6-6M7 7l-6 6"
      />
    </svg>
  </button>
`;
  alertChild.style.transition = "transform 0.75s";

  new Dismiss(alertChild, alertChild.querySelector('[aria-label="Close"]'));
  alert.appendChild(alertChild);

  alertChild.style.animation = "wipe-alert 0.75s ease-in-out";

  setTimeout(() => {
    alertChild.style.transform = "translateX(100%)";
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert.removeChild(alertChild);
    }, 0.75 * 1000);
  }, timeoutTime);
}

const uploadInput = document.querySelector("#upload input");
uploadInput.onchange = () => {
  showSuccessAlert("Uploading Image")
}
showSuccessAlert("Working When Called Outside onchange")
```

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
#alert {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  right: 10px;
  max-width: 300px;
  z-index:100;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.7.0/flowbite.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  
<div id="alert"></div>

<div id="upload" class="ms-auto w-screen flex content-center justify-center flex-wrap items-center my-10">
  <div class="text-4xl my-5 text-purple-700 font-bold">
    <svg class="w-6 h-6 text-purple-700 inline" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 18">
          <path
            d="M18 0H2a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v14a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h16a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2Zm-5.5 4a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0 3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0-3Zm4.376 10.481A1 1 0 0 1 16 15H4a1 1 0 0 1-.895-1.447l3.5-7A1 1 0 0 1 7.468 6a.965.965 0 0 1 .9.5l2.775 4.757 1.546-1.887a1 1 0 0 1 1.618.1l2.541 4a1 1 0 0 1 .028 1.011Z"
          />
        </svg> Upload Photos
  </div>
  <div class="relative flex items-center justify-center w-11/12">
    <label for="dropzone-file" class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full h-64 border-2 border-gray-300 border-dashed rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-bray-800 dark:bg-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:border-gray-500 dark:hover:bg-gray-600">
          <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center pt-5 pb-6">
            <svg
              class="w-16 h-16 mb-4 text-purple-700 dark:text-purple-900"
              aria-hidden="true"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              fill="none"
              viewBox="0 0 20 16"
            >
              <path
                stroke="currentColor"
                stroke-linecap="round"
                stroke-linejoin="round"
                stroke-width="2"
                d="M13 13h3a3 3 0 0 0 0-6h-.025A5.56 5.56 0 0 0 16 6.5 5.5 5.5 0 0 0 5.207 5.021C5.137 5.017 5.071 5 5 5a4 4 0 0 0 0 8h2.167M10 15V6m0 0L8 8m2-2 2 2"
              />
            </svg>
            <p class="mb-2 text-lg text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
              <span class="font-semibold text-purple-700 dark:text-purple-950"
                >Click to upload</span
              >
              or drag and drop
            </p>
            <p class="text-xs text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
              PNG, JPG, or JPEG
            </p>
          </div>
          <input
            id="dropzone-file"
            type="file"
            class="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full opacity-0 cursor-pointer"
            multiple
            accept="image/jpg, image/png, image/jpeg"
          />
        </label>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.7.0/flowbite.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, i wasted hours trying different combinations to find root of the problem. Also why is the transition-opacity option not working? is it due to custom styling. I also tried passing it from JS API, but it still doesn't work